# This reaction collection filter is always returning 1

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I made a method for `client`. It is supposed to calculate how many reactions there are for 2 different emojis, and return the difference.

```js
client.calcscore = async function(m) {
    //m is an instance of Message
    if(m.partial) await m.fetch()
    let upvotes = m.reactions.cache.filter(r => r.emoji.name === '⬆️').size;
    let downvotes = m.reactions.cache.filter(r => r.emoji.name === '⬇️').size
    return upvotes - downvotes
}
```

The "score" is kind of like Stack Overflow's score. However `upvotes` always returns 1 and `downvotes` always returns 1. This means the function always returns 0. This is called in a reaction event, and I *know* I am reacting:

[image: I reacted]

Does it have something to do with caching? I await fetching the reaction and message in the event, and then pass it in. I even tried getting my second bot to react, and it still got 1.

Comment: What are your client intents?

Comment: I have the reaction intents, otherwise I wouldn’t get the event. Same with message intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `r.count` in your filter to get an `int` of how many people have given a reaction. Use that number to measure your scores.

Comment: It works. I suppose it has something to do with caching